# base_url not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing a Web Application. 
I have created a Controller called Starter.
In the navigation I have put a link like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'welcome';?>">Starter</a>
```

It is returning a 404 Object not found Error.

Comment: can you copy the full error message here?

Comment: please post more of the code. Did you load the helper('url')?
something like $this->load->helper('url');
This link has a good explanation of base_url()

Comment: yeah i load it in autoload file.All other urls ara working.But when I call a controler like which i have been posted it is not working

Comment: Try with index.php in url `<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome');?>">Starter</a>` If that works then you need a htaccess for main directory to remove the index.php

Comment: Your link is "calling" the Welcome Controller. Does that exist?

Comment: @TharinduSandaruwan as [WolfGang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219042/about-url-is-not-working-in-codeigniter#comment83420262_48219042) said did you try this

Comment: yeah that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>'welcome'">Starter</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome');?>">Starter</a>
```